# How to List out all the tables on the SQL server which do not have a Clustered index?

Tags: sql-server, clustered-index

SQL Query to retrieve the tables on the server which does not have the clustered index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query `sys.indexes` using:

```
select distinct [table] = object_name(object_id) 
from sys.indexes where index_id=0 and objectproperty(object_id, 'IsuserTable') = 1
```

or:

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id]), name 
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTYEX([object_id], 'TableHasClustIndex') = 0;
```

If you are looking for a complete index analysis, you should take a look at Brent's script [blitzindex](http://www.brentozar.com/blitzindex/). It is very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

While this looks like more code, I think it's more straightforward because

- it mimics what is asked in English more closely (find the tables without a clustered index, not the tables with an index_id of 0)
- it doesn't need to apply `distinct`
- it avoids [pesky metadata functions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-metadata-helper-functions) and awkward functions like `objectproperty/ex`
- it includes the schema

  ```
  SELECT [table] = s.name + N'.' + t.name 
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
    ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes AS i
        WHERE i.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        AND i.index_id = 1
    );
  ```